# r - Remove Unicode replacement character from a string

Tags: r, regex, unicode

I have a dataset of a hundred million rows, out of which about 10 have some sort of Unicode replacement character. Text representation of this particular character is "< U+FFFD>" (remove whitespace), however there are others, too.

I want to remove the character, but i wasn't able to come up with a way to do that.

```
str <- "торгово производственн��я компания"
gsub("<U+FFFD>", "", str)
"торгово производственн��я компания"
```

If i need to provide any additional info please let me know. Also i would be very grateful for an explanation of what exactly is happening here (as in why a normal gsub doesn't work and why it displays like that)

Comment: Try `gsub("\uFFFD", "", str, fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, that worked perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `gsub` function with a regex pattern as the first argument. `<U+FFFD>` pattern matches `<`, 1 or more `U` symbols, and then a `FFFD>` sequence of chars.

It would work like this:

```
> str2 <- "торгово <UUUFFFD> производственн��я компания"
> gsub("<U+FFFD>", "", str2)
[1] "торгово  производственн��я компания"
```

Use a mere literal string replacement:

```
> str <- "торгово производственн��я компания"
> gsub("\uFFFD", "", str, fixed=TRUE)
[1] "торгово производствення компания"
```

Comment: When I read file with `vroom`. certain column values are read as `chr "<U+00A0>KLRK1"`. Tried following the above approach, however it gives an error saying the character is not `UTF-8` . If I use the direct character vector instead of passing it from column like your answer above, it works. Wondering if there is a way to catch fix this file reading the files instead of post addressing them ? I use vroom package to read .csv files. These files are generated from excel files

Comment: @user5249203 You have a soft/hard space in the data. Try `gsub("(*UCP)\\s", " ", text, perl=TRUE)` that will "normalize" any whitespace to a regular space. Or, ``gsub("\\xA0", " ", text, perl=TRUE)`` to replace all hard/soft spaces with regular spaces.

Comment: thank you for the response. Its throwing and error invalid UTF-8. I created a question [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66340581/u00a0-special-characters-when-reading-a-csv-file) can you please have a look ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked best for me when applying this same concept to an entire data frame.

```
# Remove embedded unicode characters in the data frame
df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character),~ str_remove_all(.,"\\s*\u200b")))
```